# How do I create a UITabBarController with a custom UITabBar class without using IB?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I can create a `UINavigationController` with custom bar classes by using `initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:`.  There doesn't seem to be an equivalent for `UITabBarController`, so how do I get it to use a custom `UITabBar` class?

Every solution I've seen so far is unsuitable because either

1. It uses IB
2. It adds a second tab bar to the `UITabBarController` instead of changing its existing one, or
3. It throws `UITabBarController` away and makes a new controller class.

I want a real `UITabBarController` created in code using a custom class for its tab bar.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is surprisingly hard! The best I've come up with is subclassing `UITabBarController` and then doing this in the `init`:

```
super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

object_setClass(self.tabBar, CustomTabBar.self)
(self.tabBar as? CustomTabBar)?.setup()
```

Unfortunately you can't set the class before the call to `super.init` (not in Swift anyway), and so by the time you change the class the `init` method has already been run and so won't be called on your custom subclass. To get around this, I've just added a `setup()` method to do all my customisation in.

Another option in Swift is to extend `UITabBar` and do something like this:

```
extension UITabBar {

    open override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        super.willMove(toSuperview: newSuperview)
        /// Customise in here.
    }

    // Modify the height.
    open override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: size.width, height: 64.0)
    }
}
```

However this will affect all instances of `UITabBar`, so I prefer the first option.

Comment: What about subclassed `UITabbar` which having few properties ?

Answer (score 6):

This solution from [ESTabBarControlller](https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController/blob/master/Sources/ESTabBarController.swift#L90,L100), for replace native UITabBar without IB.

```
open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tabBar = { () -> CustomTabBar in 
        let tabBar = CustomTabBar()
        tabBar.delegate = self
        return tabBar
    }()
    self.setValue(tabBar, forKey: "tabBar")
}
```

Comment: why do you use private api?

Comment: @Gargo , in my opinion, tabBar is a public property of the UITabBarController, which is inherited from NSObject, so it sets value with KVC.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621174-tabbar

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible.

Here is the Apple Documentation that talks about the `tabBar` property of `UITabBarController`.

> You should never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar object itself
>   stored in this property. If you attempt to do so, the tab bar view
>   throws an exception. To configure the items for your tab bar
>   interface, you should instead assign one or more custom view
>   controllers to the viewControllers property. The tab bar collects the
>   needed tab bar items from the view controllers you specify.
>
> The tab bar view provided by this property is only for situations
>   where you want to display an action sheet using the showFromTabBar:
>   method of the UIActionSheet class.

Comment: Why is it declared as "open var" then?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't do this. Your best option to do this without IB is to have your own UIViewController (not subclassing UITabBarController) and then add your own subclass of UITabBar to that Controller.

You may also want to review the Controller Hierarchy if you decide to follow this approach.