# How to set a custom tabBar to my custom TabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, autolayout

My custom tab Bar:

```
class MyTabBar: UITabBar {

}

My custom tab Bar Controller: 

class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

}
```

My question is how I can use my custom tab bar in my custom tab bar controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a UITabBarController with a custom UITabBar class without using IB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227378/how-do-i-create-a-uitabbarcontroller-with-a-custom-uitabbar-class-without-using)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to that by setting the value of 'tabBar' to my custom tabBar.

setValue(MycustomTabBar(frame: tabBar.frame), forKey: "tabBar")

```
class MyCustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setValue(TBar(frame: tabBar.frame), forKey: "tabBar")
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        createShape()
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a bad solution because you involve private api